# Vue JS Jest : mount() doesn't render properly

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs

MyView.vue :

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="obj in myObjs" :key="obj.ref">
        <MyChild :obj="obj" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

export default class MyView extends Vue {
  myObjs: MyObj[] = []

  mounted () {
    this.myObjs = await api.getGreatObjs()
    // this.myObjs is like expected
  }
}
```

MyView.spec.ts :

```
beforeEach( () => {
  localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(Vuetify)

  jest.mock('axios')
  jest.spyOn(api, 'getGreatObjs')
    .mockImplementation( () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve([new MyObj({name: 'toto', value: 45}), ...])
    }))
})

it('should render', () => {
  wrapper = mount(MyView, {
    stubs: ['router-link']
  })
  expect(wrapper.findAll(MyChild).length).toBe(2)
})
```

Content of wrapper.html():

```
<v-container fluid=\"\"><v-container fluid=\"\"><v-row></v-row></v-container></v-container>
```

I also tried this (MyView.spec.ts):

```
describe('P1RealTime.vue', () => {
  let wrapper: any
  let localVue: any

  beforeEach( () => {
    localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuetify)
  })

  it('should render', () => {
    wrapper = mount(MyView, {
      localVue: localVue,
      stubs: ['router-link']
    })
    expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('')
  })
})
```

Console result :

```
Expected: ""
Received: "<div class=\"container container--fluid\"><div class=\"container container--fluid\"><div></div></div>"
```

There is nothing inside "row" (`<v-row></v-row>`) or "div" (`<div></div>`) but there should be multiple MyChild ; so, I don't understand.
Could you help me ?

Comment: Questions without Types are not about TypeScript. Removed the tag.

Comment: can you tried to update wrapper? await wrapper.forceUpdate();

Comment: What is "myObjs"? How do you pass them to the component in your test?

Comment: @Berkay Kaan I tried await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate(), but nothing (wrapper.forceUpdate() doesn't exist)

Comment: @Rara I have in my Vue class : myObjs: MyObj[] = []. I get them from an API via Axios, but I mock this with : jest.spyOn(api, 'getGreatObjs')
      .mockImplementation( () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve([new MyObj({name: 'toto', value: 45}), ...])
      }))

Comment: @Rara In order to test, I replaced "myObjs: MyObj[] = []" by "myObjs: MyObj[] = [new MyObj({name: 'toto', value: 45})]" ; and then myObjs in correctly displayed.

Comment: The same when deleting the mock

Comment: Try add logging in the `mockImplementation` of `getGreatObjs`. Is it executed?

Comment: I logged `this.myObjs` in MyView.ts and th value is ok

Comment: However, when I print the entire first entry of my list, in MyVew, I get `MyObj{
          startDate: [Getter/Setter],
          startDateTimeAgo: [Getter/Setter],
          ...}` ; so I don't understand why there are these "[Getter/Setter]" although each value is correct when I print them individually ; besides, the objects are correctly printed in my `mockImplementation`